# ODI FILE TO TABLE (dynamic file name and Location)

Tags: oracle

I have developed  File-table(Oracle)scenario 12c, everything is all good on my local machine when I ran individually. I want to get the file name and location dynamically as start up parameters. Built PKG with 2 declared variable( Name and location) followed by  the file interface( included file location in PS corresponding LS) and in model resource I only included #project.variable(location.) I ran the scn got the 2 variables ( file name and file location) it is success but here comes the issue nothing is getting loaded into table 0 records. What I am missing here ( agent used local agent, file is in my c directory local) does the local  agent not able to read the file if it is 11g i might put in absolute path assuming agent permissions to read file ? But its local agent and file is in local folder c its picking up the file when ran individually as mentioned with the same. Pls share your thoughts.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, to show the community your efforts.

Comment: Hello Rainer, thanks for your response. I think this is nothing to do with the  code, dynamic file name on local machine is not working when I created start up parameters for file name and location. Scenario kicked off successfully using local agent as the file is in local c directory as mentioned above after reaching the interface step it shows green success but records are not getting inserted and no steps in interface as well.